# Gender agreement with "fin de semana"

Tags: adjetivos, género, concordancia-gramatical

Would it be **el fin de semana próxima** or **el fin de semana próximo** for *next weekend*? And how would you say *last weekend* in Spanish?

Comment: I was trying to provide an answer to your question, and realized I didn't even know part of the answer I was trying to provide, so I asked a [followup question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10692/12).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since *fin* is a masculine noun and goes with *el*, adjectives that modify it go in masculine form, too. So it's *el fin de semana próximo* or *el próximo fin de semana* (this one sounds more natural to me, but the other form might be more natural in other regions).

*Last weekend* is *el fin de semana pasado*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but now my confusion is this: Why is it more natural to say el próximo fin de semana (adjective before the noun) but not el pasado fin de semana?

Comment: @AmitSchandillia Haha, you got me. I don't really know, it just is. If you say *el fin de semana próximo* or *el pasado fin de semana* it's correct, but you sound like a news anchor. I think that this case with *próximo* is the exception to the rule, most adjectives sound more natural **after** the noun they modifiy.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia According to your comment and if I understand you well, the _próximo_ and _pasado_ are in different times _future_ and _past_ respectively. To me, both sounds right but I use often **noun before the adjective** structure in this case. Example: La semana _pasada_, la semana _próxima_

Comment: @Mauricio Could this have a regional preference? Which Spanish speaking region would you be from?

Comment: @AmitSchandillia according to his profile, he's from Colombia. That might be the reason, so I'm going to modify my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia I think that you can say both "el próximo fin de semana" and "el fin de semana próximo" because "próximo" is an _situational adjetive_ and thus it doesn't state or modify a property/quality of the noun, but state it's position spatio-temporal wise. Ordinal (and situational) adj can even have different meanings when they go before or after the noun.