# La colocación del adjetivo en "fin de semana"

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, orden-de-palabras

Cuando estaba respondiendo a [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10637/12), quería decir que la forma correcta de hablar "*del fin de semana que viene*" es:

> el próximo fin de semana

y no:

> el fin de semana próximo

Y eso, según [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/335/12) que dice que el adjetivo precede al sustantivo cuando describe un atributo del sustantivo, y sigue al sustantivo cuando funciona como modificador.  Así, "*próximo*" parece como atributo.  Pero ¿por qué, entonces, "*pasado*" sigue como modificador?

Considérense los ejemplos:

1. El próximo fin de semana
2. El fin de semana próximo
3. El siguiente fin de semana
4. El fin de semana siguiente
5. El fin de semana pasado
6. El pasado fin de semana
7. El anterior fin de semana
8. El fin de semana anterior

A mí, 2 y 6 me parecen raros. ¿Es porque son incorrectos, o solo porque estoy acostumbrado a escuchar las otras formas?

¿Hay una regla que establezca cuál es la forma (más) correcta en este caso?

Comment: I would say that you are more likely to read (6) in a newspaper and hear (5) in a conversation. May sound weird to you, but its OK. To me it sounds just a little bit more formal. I find no difference between (1) and (2).

Comment: Pienso lo mismo que @Diego en referencia a las frases (5) y (6), de hecho lo comento en la pregunta que enlazas. (1) también me suena a periódico o televisión ('en el próximo capítulo...'), (2) me suena a algo que diría una persona de cierta edad, de más de 60 años; yo diría *el fin de semana que viene*. (3) y (7) me suenan raro, forzados, como si fuese una poesía (similar a 'la blanca nieve'), y (4) y (8) me suenan bien, pero sólo en caso de estar haciendo planes, no los usaría para referirme al fin de semana que viene o al pasado.

Answer (score 4):

Es cierto que anteponer el adjetivo al sustantivo puede modificar el valor expresivo del adjetivo

> Sus azules ojos vs. sus ojos azules

modificar el significado

> El pobre señor vs. el señor pobre

(el calificativo prenominal ayuda a identificar la clase, mientras que los postnominales ayudan a determinar al individuo particular dentro de la clase)

o (prenominal) indicar una cualidad o atributo del nombre

> la verde hoja; la esbelta figura

pero este no es el caso para adjetivos **situacionales** del tipo de **próximo, siguiente, anterior o posterior**, que denotan relaciones de secuenciación espacio-temporal entre entidades.

De acuerdo a [esta fuente](http://palabrasparavioleta.weebly.com/uploads/9/6/4/6/9646574/en_torno_al_sustantivo_y_adjetivo_en_el_espa_ol_actual_aspectos_cognitivos_sem_ticos_morfo_sint_cticos_y_lexicogen_ticos_configuracion_e_interpretacion_de_los_adjetivos_.pdf) los adjetivos **circunstanciales** no cambian semánticamente en posición pre o post nominal:

> Los adjetivos postnominales son por lo general cualitativos [...] son siempre clasificadores y 'restringen' la denotación del nombre. Ahora bien, ciertos adjetivos temporo-deícticos como futuro, próximo, que desde un punto de vista semántico son una subparte de los circunstanciales, también pueden aparecer postnominalmente (*el anterior presidente*, pero también *el presidente anterior*). **Sin embargo, la alternancia en estas dos posiciones no tiene en este caso las mismas implicaciones de significado que en el caso de los adjetivos calificativos regulares**, puesto que la interpretación de los adjetivos temporales permanece constante con independencia de la posición que ocupen.

Por tanto, a diferencia de otros tipos de adjetivos, el valor semántico los adjetivos circunstanciales (o siguiente, anterior, próximo o pasado) no varía en posición prenominal o postnominal.

Parece ser que este puede ser el caso también para otros adjetivos **eventivos** (temporales, locativos y de manera)

> El próximo año. / Mi antiguo jefe. / La última reunión. / El reciente atentado. / El remoto incidente. / El actual intendente. / La cercana casa. / El beso cortés.

y adjetivos **aspectuales**

> Las constantes idas y venidas. / Las periódicas revisiones. / El largo adiós. / La ocasional visita. / Las reiteradas entradas. / Las esporádicas crisis.

(estos ejemplos son de [esta web](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Adjetivo-clasificaci%C3%B3n.htm))

Los ordinales son una excepción evidente. Según [esta fuente](http://rua.ua.es/dspace/bitstream/10045/6098/1/ELUA_19_05.pdf):

> los adjetivos **ordinales** del español tienen distintas propiedades semánticas y sintácticas en posición pre y postnominal:
>
> Este es el **segundo** piso **segundo** que visitamos.
>
> El **segundo** capítulo (que he leído) vs. el capítulo **segundo** (del libro)
>
> El  **primer** capítulo **primero** (que leo)

Así que parece ser que `el próximo fin de semana` y `el fin de semana próximo` tiene el mismo significado (se puede sustituir "próximo" por "siguiente", "anterior" o "posterior")