# When does the adjective come before the noun in Spanish?

Tags: gramática

Normally, the adjective follows the noun in Spanish, as in "el coche rojo" (not "el rojo coche")

However, I came across this sentence:

"*Entonces siguió el camino lentamente hasta que llegaron a una posada, o pequeño hotel.*"

Why is it not:

"*Entonces siguió el camino lentamente hasta que llegaron a una posada, o hotel pequeño.*"

?

Could "pequeño" be in either position (before or after "hotel")? Is it simply a matter of taste, or is there a guideline to go by as to when the adjective comes before the noun.

Comment: [Significance of adjective placement](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/328/significance-of-adjective-placement?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: You also my fin [this answer](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10699/5481) interesting or helpful

Comment: Remember to change the conjunction _o_ by _u_ when the next sound is another _o_: "... hasta que llegaron a una posada, **u** hotel pequeño".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes changing the order of an adjetive can change the way they modify the noun and/or become more expressive.

With

> llegaron a una posada, o hotel **pequeño**.

the speaker explains that the hotel was small. With

> llegaron a una posada, o **pequeño** hotel.

the speaker emphasizes the the hotel was small.

In Spanish we have a special type of adjectives called *epítetos*. These are adjetives that highlight an obvious characteristic of the noun (thus, being completely unnecessary). Some examples would be:

- the **white** snow / La **blanca** nieve
- the **cold** ice / El **frío** hielo
- La **roja** sangre, el **cálido** sol, etc.

As you can guess it is used for poetic value, since we already know that the snow is white, the ice cold, the blood red, etc. Also, the *epíteto* doesn't need to go in front of the name, but usually it does, since this grants a more poetic value.

In you example, **pequeño** is not an *epíteto* (since a hotel could be big or small), but the use of a pre-nominal adjetive serves the same function as the *epíteto*, not your *pointing* or *declaring* a quality of the noun, but **stressing** or **emphasizing** that quality.

Other exmaples of this would be:

> El hotel pequeño / El pequeño hotel
>
> Su coche rápido/ Su rápido coche
>
> Sus ojos azules / Sus azules ojos